# Talend Transpose the input text to excel

Tags: talend

Hi guys i have the input file in `.txt` and i want the output in `excel` format `<br/>`
Input

```
m1;01;8.8;02
m2;02;8.7;03
m3;03;8.8;04
m4;04;8.5;05
m5;05;8.4;01
```

output

> ```
> m1  m2  m3  m4  m5
> 8.8 8.7 8.6 8.5 8.4
> ```

i used **tDenormalize** to transpose but the output is not exactly as i want

the output kinda looks like

```
m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 <br/>
```

---

so, someone please help me to get the output and i'm new to talend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I got the answer and it's very simple 
So, i want to separate text from special characters in my case its semicolon.. what i did is i just used the **tFileInputDelimited** to take my input text file then in the component i used field separator as **";"** and in the **tmap** i mapped the first and third column for my output and used **tDenormalize** to transpose the output 
So, if anyone find this useful it be glad to share for me

Answer (score 2):

You could use the components tFileExcel-Components by Jan Lolling : [link to the latest version](https://exchange.talend.com/#marketplaceproductoverview:marketplace=marketplace%252F1&p=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F542&pi=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F542%252Fitems%252F2897) (30/01/2019).

The output component (tFileExcelSheetOutput) has an option "Exchange rows/columns" that should do what you want.

Comment: I'm new to this talend tool so i want to learn without using any external files.  Please help me to get the output using talend functions... Thank You

Comment: @RajaGopal : I understand, but the native Excel component are so limited that if you have anything to do with Excel i would encourage you to use tFileExcel instead.

Comment: thank you for your advice i'll keep that in my mind once again thank you